# Remote MYSQL Connection Failure 2003 hy000

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to remotely connect to my mysql. So Far I've done these steps but havent gotten anywhere.

1. inside /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf i have set bind-address to

   10.240.0.2 (internal ip address)
2. CREATE USER 'TESTUSER'@'10.240.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY '';
3. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'TESTUSER'@'10.240.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY
   '';
4. flush privileges;
5. restarted mysql

when i tried connecting to mysql via mysql -h 35.196.118.14 -u testuser -p i get the error 2003 hy000.

its worth mentioning im using ubuntu 16.04 on a google cloud compute server...

Can anyone help? thanks in advance

Comment: did you include `skip-name-resolve` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve) option in the MySQL  configuration?

Comment: i added your suggestion of create user 'testuser'@'::1' identified by pw;

and i stilll get the same error @spencer7539

Comment: might be worth looking at the /etc/mysql/my.cnf and seeing if the bind-address if is set.  If it is you can remove it and restart mysql.  That has caught me in the past.

Comment: im using mysql 5.6+ so its in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. the folder /etc/mysql/my.cnf doesnt contain anything.